# Почему изменился массив

Tags: javascript, map

3дравствуйте, помогите плз новичку, не могу понять как такое получается

```
    let a =[11, 22, 33];
    
    let b= a.map(( item, index, array) =>{  
       if (index==2) {  
         array[index+1]= 55;  
    }  
    return item;  
    })  
    
console.log("mas B", b);  
console.log("mas A", a);
```

// Почему изменился массив "а" ведь "map" создает новый массив?
// Почему изменился только массив "а", ведь если изменился массив "а" значит должен измениться массив "b" (исходя из последовательности операций)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Массив `a` изменился потому, что третим аргументом в функцию передаются имменно он.

```
const new_array = arr.map(function callback( currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
                                                                    ^^^^^^

Функция callback, создающая элемент в новом массиве, принимает три аргумента:

currentValue - Текущий обрабатываемый элемент массива.
index - Индекс текущего обрабатываемого элемента в массиве.

array - Массив, по которому осуществляется проход.
^^^^^^^
```

массив `b` не поменялся потому, что сам `item` не был никак ни разу изменён внутри функции (не были применены изменения к item), при этом сама функция `map` возвращает новый массив, сделаный из исходного сразу в самом начале метода. И он не связан по ссылке с первым никак

Answer (score 1):

У вас в map идёт `array[index+1]= 55;`из-за этой строки меняется исходный массив а.
Массив b не меняется потому что метод `map` создаёт новый массив из исходного и они никак по связаны.

Comment: Не разу не пользовался 3-м аргументом. Там ссылка на итерируемый массив. Добавлю: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map